# Embedding multiple sigma.js graphs in one web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sigma.js

I am trying to display two graphs, imported from JSON format, in one wabpage, each in a different div element. However, when I include the  for each network in separate divs as follows,

```
    <div id="container">
    <script>
      sigma.parsers.json('graph.json', {
        container: 'container',
        settings: {
          defaultNodeColor: '#000',
        }
      });
    </script>
    </div>
```

(this is repeated two times, one for each graph)

The graphs appear on top of each other. More specifically, the canvas elements for both graphs get stuck together. How may I resolve this? The sigmajs.org website is a perfect example of what I am trying to achieve here. All the examples html pages I've seen contain one single graph.

I'm new to javascript, so I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An `id` on an html page must be unique, so if you repeat this html block, you will have two  with the id `container`.

I think your problem come from that.

Cheers.